# RoR 3.x - create gem file with engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've created simple Engine for my App written in RoR 3.0.x

How can I create gem file with this engine? Or how can I distribute this engine? My App is simple CMS system and I want engines to add more features for it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the gem `jeweler` for that. Here's an [article](http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/03/05/rails-3-plugins---part-2---writing-an-engine/) that might help you out in packaging a rails engine.

Comment: Yes! jeweler! For me it still is the easiest way to create gems. And it creates your gemspec based on your `Gemfile`. Much easier imho.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler